# How to hide and show paragraph on click of radio button

Tags: jquery, css, materialize

I am trying to hide and show paragraph with respect to radio button clicked. And also i want the first radio button to be active when the user lands on the page.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="BusinessForm">
  <p class="showBusinessForm" style="display:none">Business</p>
</div>
<div class="TechnicalForm">
  <p class="showTechnicalForm" style="display:none">Technical</p>
</div>
<div class="LoginForm">
  <p class="showLoginForm" style="display:none">login</p>
</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".showBusinessForm").show();
});
$(".showBusinessForm").click(function(){
    $(".showTechnicalForm").hide();
    $(".showLoginForm").hide();
    $(".showBusinessForm").show();
});
$(".showTechnicalForm").click(function(){
    $(".showTechnicalForm").show();
    $(".showLoginForm").hide();
    $(".showBusinessForm").hide();
});
$(".showLoginForm").click(function(){
    $(".showTechnicalForm").hide();
    $(".showLoginForm").show();
    $(".showBusinessForm").hide();
});
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue?

Comment: I think you confuse Radio buttons with paragraph tags

Comment: Kindly use https://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can fully understand the issue.

Comment: @M.Nabeel Why use jsfiddle when he can use the integrated snippet tool that StackOverflow already provided

Comment: Can you add the html part of your radio button also

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I was using wrong id to click. My radio button id's were different.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have a dynamical approach instead of specific for each div.

You can select you target form to show with your radio btn by using the value and the class of the form.

```js
$(".radiobtn").click(function(){
  $(".form").hide();
  $("."+$(this).val()).show();
})
```

```css
.form{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Business <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" value="BusinessForm" name="showForm"/>
Technical <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" value="TechnicalForm" name="showForm"/>
Login <input type="radio" class="radiobtn" value="LoginForm" name="showForm"/>

<div class="form BusinessForm">
  <p>Business</p>
</div>
<div class="form TechnicalForm">
  <p>Technical</p>
</div>
<div class="form LoginForm">
  <p>login</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to modify your script too much. Here is working example based on your script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").change(function() {
    if($("#business").prop('checked') == true) {
      $(".BusinessForm").show();
      $(".TechnicalForm").hide();
      $(".LoginForm").hide();
    }else if($("#technical").prop('checked') == true) {
      $(".BusinessForm").hide();
      $(".TechnicalForm").show();
      $(".LoginForm").hide();
    }else if($("#login").prop('checked') == true) {
      $(".BusinessForm").hide();
      $(".TechnicalForm").hide();
      $(".LoginForm").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-buttons">
  <div class="group">
    <label for="business">Business radio</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="business" checked />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="technical">Business radio</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="technical" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="login">Business radio</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="login" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="BusinessForm">
  <p class="showBusinessForm">Business</p>
</div>
<div class="TechnicalForm" style="display: none;">
  <p class="showTechnicalForm">Technical</p>
</div>
<div class="LoginForm" style="display: none;">
  <p class="showLoginForm">login</p>
</div>
```